# Prove that the vectors are Q conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

> $Q \in S_{++}^n$ and a set of linearly independent vectors $\{p_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$
>
> Then a set of vectors $\{d_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is
> generated as follows
>
> $d_k = p_k-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{p_k^T \ Q \ d_i}{d_i^T \ Q \ d_i}d_i$
>
> Prove that the vectors $\{d_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are Q-conjugate.

---

This came up on a quiz and I'm not sure of how to attempt it. A hint that was later provided is of proving through induction but I can't seem to formulate the base step. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conjecture $P(k)$: For all $ 1 \le k \le n-1, d_k^T Qd_j = 0 ,\forall j < k$

Hence the base case is just  $d_1^TQd_0=\left(p_1 - \frac{p_1^TQd_0}{d_0Qd_0}d_0 \right)^T Qd_0=0$.